# Check if file name in current URL is not equal to $a or $b

Tags: php, if-statement

I am attempting to check if the file name of the current URL is not equal to two values:

```
$fn = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

if ($fn !== 'blah.php' OR $fn !== 'bleh.php') {
    // do something
}
```

For some reason, this if statement fails.

However, if I use simply:

```
$fn = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if ($fn !== 'blah.php') {
   // do something
}
```

This works fine.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Use && (AND) not OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be `AND` operator,

```
if ($fn !== 'blah.php' AND $fn !== 'bleh.php') {...}
```

If you have there more values, you can use `in_array` too.

```
if (!in_array($fn, array('blah.php', 'bleh.php'))) {....}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things. 
first : use AND instead of OR
Second : if you are comparing with file name only use

```
$fn = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly right , you have to just replace `OR` with &&. Use the code below

```
$fn = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

if ($fn !== 'blah.php' && $fn !== 'bleh.php') {
    // do something
}
```

Hope this helps you